# Product CSV importer Woocommerce tool in frontend

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, import-csv

I want to show the native CSV product import tool of Woocommerce in the frontend so that users with certain roles (vendors) can use it to upload their products to the website.

I have never used the native Woocommerce importer since it appeared in the 3.0 update but I have clues on how I should start.

in the WC documentation I found the WC_Product_CSV_Importer class, inside I found the method: Initialize importer

```
    Initialize importer.

    __construct( string $file, array $params = array()  )


    Parameters
        $file  --> File to read.
        $params  --> Arguments for the parser.
```

and the method: read file

```
Read file

read_file( )
```

I also think if I find the product importer metabox, I could work with it.

Has anyone tried to do something similar?

Any opinion is well received

Woocommerce class: https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product_CSV_Importer.html

Answer (score 0):

The Woocommerce Rest API enables you to offer users the ability to post new products from the frontend of the site.

[batch create, update and delete multiple products](http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?php#batch-update-products)

```
<?php
$data = [
'create' => [
    [
        'name' => 'Woo Single #1',
        'type' => 'simple',
        'regular_price' => '21.99',
        'virtual' => true,
        'downloadable' => true,
        'downloads' => [
            [
                'name' => 'Woo Single',
                'file' => 'http://demo.woothemes.com/woocommerce/wp-content/uploads/sites/56/2013/06/cd_4_angle.jpg'
            ]
        ],
        'categories' => [
            [
                'id' => 11
            ],
            [
                'id' => 13
            ]
        ],
        'images' => [
            [
                'src' => 'http://demo.woothemes.com/woocommerce/wp-content/uploads/sites/56/2013/06/cd_4_angle.jpg',
                'position' => 0
            ]
        ]
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'New Premium Quality',
        'type' => 'simple',
        'regular_price' => '21.99',
        'description' => 'Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.',
        'short_description' => 'Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.',
        'categories' => [
            [
                'id' => 9
            ],
            [
                'id' => 14
            ]
        ],
        'images' => [
            [
                'src' => 'http://demo.woothemes.com/woocommerce/wp-content/uploads/sites/56/2013/06/T_2_front.jpg',
                'position' => 0
            ],
            [
                'src' => 'http://demo.woothemes.com/woocommerce/wp-content/uploads/sites/56/2013/06/T_2_back.jpg',
                'position' => 1
            ]
        ]
    ]
],
'update' => [
    [
        'id' => 799,
        'default_attributes' => [
            [
                'id' => 6,
                'name' => 'Color,
                'option' => 'Green'
            ],
            [
                'id' => 0,
                'name' => 'Size',
                'option' => 'M'
            ]
        ]
    ]
],
'delete' => [
    794
]
];

print_r($woocommerce->post('products/batch', $data));
?>
```

Comment: Thank you @HashimWarren Can bulk products be imported ?